# Can't pass data to chart.js graph

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I’m trying to pass my data to the graph but it won't work. If I add numbers to it manually like

```
data: [1,2,3]
```

Than it works. In my code you'll see that I console.logged my `data.weight` and `data.goal`. They appear in the console as they should.

Here's the code:

```
var endpoint = '/api/data';
    var defaultDataW = [];
    var defaultDataG = [];
   
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.weight);
            console.log(data.goal);
            defaultDataW = data.weight;
            defaultDataG = data.goal;
            var graph = document.getElementById("weight-graph");

            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

    var dataFirst = {
    label: "Your Weight (Kg)",
    data: defaultDataW,
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'red'
    };

    var dataSecond = {
    label: "Your Goal (Kg)",
    data: defaultDataG,
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'blue'
    };

    var DateData = {
     labels: [],    //Dates will be here
      datasets: [dataFirst, dataSecond]
    };

    var chartOptions = {
     legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'top',
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 80,
      fontColor: 'black'
     }
    }
      };

       var lineChart = new Chart(graph, {
        type: 'line',
        data: DateData,
        options: chartOptions
            });
             },
             error: function(error_data){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(error_data);
        }
       })

        })
```

Comment: show what you see in the console (from "They appear in the console as they should.")  You likely have a string, not an array (a very common problem....)

Comment: They appear as integers.

Comment: Even though you didn't show (as I asked) the data, you still said what the problem is.....  Look at your own "what works" - - it is an array.....  Now, look at what doesn't work.... (integers, perhaps, or strings {often happens} - whatever is NOT an array....)  When you set your data to be like what works, it will work (again, note that data in console may LOOK like integers, but be strings (I say this over and over as it is a very common issue - and you did not show your 'endpoint' code, so it could be JSON strings...)  At any rate, you need to make your data an ARRAY for it to work.

Comment: They appeard like this: 70 so not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing most everything right, but you are changing 'type' of the data.....

what you are doing RIGHT

```
var defaultDataW = [];
```

This sets the data to an ARRAY.

Though, in the ajax, you are doing this:

```
defaultDataW = data.weight;
```

Which, by your other comments, clearly says that 'data.weight' is an INTEGER.

So, when you try to use that (now INTEGER) as data in a Chart

```
data: defaultDataW,
```

It doesn't work (and, no surprise......)

Chart.js requires an ARRAY (at minimum) to work - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/data-structures/

Now, how can you fix this?????

Pretty simple......

In your ajax, change

```
defaultDataW = data.weight;
```

To ADD to the ARRAY (instead of replacing the array with an integer....)

```
defaultDataW.push(data.weight);
```

In case you add other code later (or for future projects, putting things in a function, etc....), you might want to also learn about a way to CLEAR that array.  It doesn't hurt to do it now, though the way your code is it really should not be needed.  I'm including it here for others to reference, etc.

Before doing a 'push' (certainly if you are doing a loop, etc.), you may need to clear the array first, like this:

```
defaultDataW.length = 0;
```

This will empty the array and then you can 'push' what you really want in there.  If the array is not empty and you push, then you will have the old data as well as the new (of course, depending on what you are doing, that may be a good thing - though in this case, it is not)